# Integrate jQuery zoom effect with magazine-flipping Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a jquery zoom [plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom) within a turn.js magazine [flipping effect](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/03/instagram-magazine-php-jquery/).  I've got them both working separately, but can't get the zoom effect within each magazine page like I'd want.  Some of the code is below.  All ideas are appreciated, thanks.

```
        <!-- Zoom script -->
<script src='jquery.zoom.js'></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#ex1').zoom();
});
</script>

        <!-- Zoom html -->
 <span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
   <img src='pages/daisy.jpg' width='555' height='320' alt='Daisy on the Ohoopee'/>
 </span>


        <!-- Magazine html -->
 <div id="magazine"> 
   <div style="background-image:url(pages/01.jpg);">
 </div>
   <div style="background-image:url(pages/02.jpg);">
 </div>
   <div style="background-image:url(pages/03.jpg);">
 </div>
```

Comment: If the `zoom` plugin uses `img` elements and the `magazine` script uses element `background-image`, there's a fundamental mismatch going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in similar situations i used successfully [anythingZoomer](http://css-tricks.com/anythingzoomer-jquery-plugin/)
it makes easy to zoom arbitrary html elements, given taht a bit of tweaking is needed in order to suit your needs